# Change my Application appearance as Vista

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to change my Windows based application appearance like Vista. how can i do it. is there any Dll to use ???? 
thank you

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it, do you want it to look like Vista or not ?

Try getting into WPF, I think it will give you the freedom you're looking for... :)

Comment: the thing is i already create da application.Now i want to change da interface appearance.something like buttons...buttons like Office 2007,Vista,W7

Comment: Using WPF, you will have to learn XAML from the bottom up, but what you gain from this is a full division between UI and application logic, so changing the UI in the future will be much easier for you.

Comment: Ya thats true. but at this moment i want to make my interface better. using nice buttons,icons and stuff.

Comment: WPF is the best way to go in the case of c# winforms. Using the old winforms technology you'll have to recreate your own controls which will take a lot longer

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WPF, do this:
http://www.browsoft.com/tutorials/DefaultTheme.html